# Reading data from a file and storing each line in an array?

Tags: c++, file-io

I have a file with lines of integers. I want to read each line into a slot in my array. I have the code below, but it does not work. I'm not sure if I'm on the right track.

```
void Read_Save() {
    ifstream in;
    int arr[100];
    string line;
    in.open("file.txt");
    while (in.peek() != EOF)
    {
        getline(in, line, '\n');
        strcpy(arr, line.c_str());
    }
    in.clear(); in.close();
}
```

Comment: you cannot input an array of integer with `strcpy`

Comment: While `while (in.peek() != EOF)` will work, and good on you for not falling into the test for EOF before reading EOF trap,  you may find `while (getline(in, line, '\n'))` better because it save you the `peek` and catches more failure cases than just EOF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to parse the integer value out of the string.

First, let's fix your loop:

```
int pos = 0;
while( std::getline(in, line) && pos < 100 )
{
    int value = 0;

    // Insert chosen parsing method here

    arr[pos++] = value;
}
```

Here is a non-exhaustive list of common options:

1. Use [`std::strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol)

   ```
   // Will return 0 on error (indistinguishable from parsing actual 0)
   value = std::strtol( line.c_str(), nullptr, 10  );
   ```
2. Use [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)

   ```
   // Will throw exception on error
   value = std::stoi( line );
   ```
3. Build a [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) and read from it:

   ```
   std::istringstream iss( line );
   iss >> value;
   if( !iss ) {
       // Failed to parse value.
   }
   ```
4. Use [`std::sscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf)

   ```
   if( 1 != std::sscanf( line.c_str(), "%d", &value ) )
   {
       // Failed to parse value.
   }
   ```

Now, note the bounds-test on the loop checking `pos < 100`.  This is because your array has a storage limit.  Actually, you have also overridden the global one with a local one in `Read_Save`, thus hiding it with a smaller array that will be lost when the function finishes.

You can have an arbitrary-sized "array" (not actually an array) using other container types provided by the standard library.  Useful ones that provide random access are `std::vector` and `std::deque`.  Let's use the vector and change the definition of `Read_Save` to be a bit more useful:

```
std::vector<int> Read_Save( std::istream & in )
{
    std::vector<int> values;
    std::string line;

    for( int line_number = 1; getline( in, line ); line_number++ )
    {
        try {
            int value = std::stoi( line );
            values.push_back( value );
        }
        catch( std::bad_alloc & e )
        {
            std::cerr << "Error (line " << line_number << "): Out of memory!" << std::endl;
            throw e;
        }
        catch( std::exception & e)
        {
            std::cerr << "Error (line " << line_number << "): " << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return values;
}
```

And finally, the call becomes:

```
std::ifstream in( "file.txt" );
std::vector<int> values = Read_Save( in );
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `strcpy()` to convert a string to an integer.  You can use [`std::strtol()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) or [`std::stoi()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol), or even a [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream), eg:

```
int arr[1000];

void Read_Save() {
    ifstream in;
    string line;
    in.open("file.txt");
    int index = 0;
    while ((index < 1000) && (getline(in, line)))
    {
        if (istringstream(line) >> arr[index])
            ++index;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the way you did it. I get this error though 
Error C2027 use of undefined type 'std::basic_istringstream<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char

Not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Did you add the include for istringstream? I mean `#include <sstream>`

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do in your case is to use `std::vector`. The code would look like this:

```
void Read_Save()
{
    std::ifstream in("file.txt");
    int value;
    std::vector<int> arr;

    while (in >> value)
        arr.push_back(value);

    for(int i(0); i < arr.size(); i++)
        std::cout << arr[i] << ", ";

    std::cout << std::endl;
    in.close();
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can replace the manual `while` loop with `std::copy()` using `std::istream_iterator` and `std::back_inserter` as the iterators, eg: `std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(in), std::istream_iterator(), std::back_inserter(arr));`